# Is my implementation of Long Polling right?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, long-polling

I am trying to implement a simple notification system for our web based system. I've read about websocket, ratchet, socket.io etc. But the problem here is, I don't really have plenty of time to implement those, so I decided to settle with long polling. However, i'm not so sure whether I'm actually doing it right, or I'm just going to spam my server once we upload our system. I've also read couple of topics about long polling but I'm not so sure how those differs to what I am currently using. So my concerns are:

**1.Can anyone tell me if I am doing long polling right?**
**2. If NOT, what should I change with my code?**

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown notifications-menu" id="notif-div">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i><?php if (!empty($notif_count)): ?><span class="label label-warning" id="notif-count"><?php echo $notif_count->notif_count?></span>
                <?php endif; ?>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <ul class="menu">
                    <?php foreach ($notifications as $key => $notification): ?>
                      <?php if ($notification->type_of_notification == 'Comment'): ?>
                        <li>
                          <a href="<?php echo $notification->href ?>">
                            <i class="ion-chatbubble"></i> <?php echo $notification->title_content ?>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      <?php elseif ($notification->type_of_notification == 'Reply'):?>
                        <li>
                          <a href="<?php echo $notification->href ?>">
                            <i class="ion-chatbubbles"></i> <?php echo $notification->title_content ?>
                          </a>
                        </li>
                      <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
  var notif = function(){
    var user_id = {
        user_id: "<?php echo $traveller_details->user_id ?>"
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: "/Home/get_notif",
      type: "POST",
      data: user_id,
      success: function (data){
          $('#notif-div').html(data);
      }
    });
  };
  setInterval(function(){
    notif();
  }, 60000);
})();
```

PHP:

```
public function get_notif()
  {
    $this->data['notif__count'] = $this->Homes->get_notif_count($this->input->post('user_id'));
    $this->data['notifications'] = $this->Homes->get_notifications($this->input->post('user_id'));
    echo '
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>';
        if (!empty($this->data['notif__count'])) {
          echo '<span class="label label-warning" id="notif-count">'.$this->data['notif__count']->notif_count.'</span>';
        }
      echo '</a>';
      echo '<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li>
          <ul class="menu">';
          foreach ($this->data['notifications'] as $key => $notification) {
            if ($notification->type_of_notification == 'Comment') {
              echo '
              <li>
                <a href="'.$notification->href.'">
                  <i class="ion-chatbubble"></i> '.$notification->title_content.'
                </a>
              </li>
              ';
            }elseif ($notification->type_of_notification == 'Reply') {
              echo '
              <li>
                <a href="'.$notification->href.'">
                  <i class="ion-chatbubbles"></i> '.$notification->title_content.'
                </a>
              </li>
              ';
            }
          }
          echo '
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      ';
  }
```

I'm not really that familiar with long polling, so I apologized. BTW, I'm using Codeigniter framework. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, it's working. However, when we consult it to someone who has an experience, he told us that our process was questionable as it would spam our server (?).

Answer (score 0):

Well your code seems correct but if you really want to go with this method you can still improve your code.

So first time on page load you will get all new notification for that user. Now store the last id of notification in session. I.e if the last inserted notification id is 200 for example simply add store 200 in your session.

when you make an ajax call to your php function get the stored notification id from the session and in your when condition add one more condition

```
->where("notification_id",">",$YOUR_ID);
```

So according to my example you will get all the notification added after id 200. Now before sending this result update the session value with latest id of notification.

In your AJAX function rather than replacing whole HTML you can simply append the new data to existing data. So rather than fetching all the Rows from DB and replacing the HTML only fetch newly added data and append.

Comment: Although you should really consider using socket. :) @cifer

Comment: Yes, will definitely do, but due to time constraint, this will do for now. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok. You can update the code according to my suggestion and also please mark the answer approved if it helped. Thanks again and good luck. :) @cifer